# Python gets ModuleNotFoundError when run the program, but can import the module in python environment

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have a trouble with importing my own package. I am in a virtual environment. And I get error as shown below.

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.test'
```

However, if I run python and import the package, there is no problem.

```
poetry run python
/home/user1/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_package.test
```

I do not know what is going on here. Hope someone can help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically that means you believe you are using the same interpreter when in fact you are not. At the top of your script, copy what is in the shebang line and run it as is.

In other words, if it reads

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

then run this instead of what you are using to call the interpreter

```
/usr/bin/env python
```

My bet is that you will not be able to import in that interpreter.

Comment: Do you mean I might use different versions of python?  I do not have shebang line in the script. It runs in a virtual environment managed by poetry and python is 3.7.5.

Comment: ok, I did not get the context from your question, and I do not use poetry. You might consider making the context more explicit.

Still, the issue can stem from path being different, or the python executable being different. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your module is in an area accessible by your file (ie. Same folder). Also make sure that there are no duplicate files

Comment: I checked and I have __init__.py for the module, no duplicated files.